# background image after the header

Tags: html, css, background-image

Working Demo: http://jsbin.com/opokev/54

I'm working on having this image as the background image and also have a header as well, however, as the demo shows my header is cutting onto the image.

How can I correct this so that first the header draws and then the background body image draws.  I still want to maintain the quality of the image as is without scaling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go http://jsbin.com/opokev/64/

just changed `top: 0` to `top: 85px` and it works.

Comment: patrick! you helped me when I asked the question from work. adding `top 85px` makes a horizontal scrollbar appear on the right.

Comment: I changed `#background img` height to `88%` and `div#masthead` height to `10%` this made the scrollbar disappear!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, the only other way would be to toss a bunch of containers about to get the effect; however, if you can use percentages, then that is the best route for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using background-position.

```
background-position: 0px 85px;
```

Could do the trick :)

Or you could try just using this:

```
#background img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I can't see any difference in these to backgrounds (thinking about scaling):

http://jsbin.com/opokev/54

http://jsbin.com/ijoyiy/2

Then again, I'm 2min away from sleeping and I haven't got my glasses on ;)

Comment: :) appreciate you answering stuff right before sleeping but in your jsbin link the image has a scrollbar. I don't want the scrollbar and don't want the image cutting off

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `img` tag and use `background-image` for the `div#background`. Then, set `background-position` to `center 85px`.

Combined CSS:

```
div#background
{
    background:url('http://i52.tinypic.com/33xd1yu.jpg') no-repeat center 85px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This will shift the background image down 85px.

Comment: You need to keep the width and height attributes at 100%. I should have made it clear to append the above code to yours.

Comment: JSBin may be rendering it incorrectly. Check the Real-Time Preview checkbox and you will see the correct result at the right side of the window.